# Why is the space between words in my source code listing so big?

Tags: listings, letterspacing

I used the following code to list my java code, but the it looks like there's too much space between words. What can I do?

```
% source code listing
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}

% citation style
\usepackage{apacite}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=bind to service call]
bindService(new Intent(this, Recognizer.class), recConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The snapshot of what I got. The code not completely shown, and space too wide, in function `bindService`.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set `columns=flexible` then spaces are not stretched as much.  Also you should allow breaking of lines, but only at whitespaces.  Finally, it is best to tell `listings` that the language being set is Java:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
% source code listing
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}

% citation style
\usepackage{apacite}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}

\lstset{language=java,columns=flexible,breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Bind to service call]
bindService(new Intent(this, Recognizer.class), recConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: might also look better using a typewriter font, or perhaps sans serif.

Comment: @daleif certainly such choices can made by setting `basicstyle=\ttfamily` or `\sffamily`...

Answer (score 8):

If you want to preserve column alignment, but want to reduce inter character spacing, set the `basewidth` option to a smaller value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for setting colors

% set the default code style
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    frame=tb, % draw a frame at the top and bottom of the code block
    tabsize=4, % tab space width
    showstringspaces=false, % don't mark spaces in strings
    numbers=left, % display line numbers on the left
    commentstyle=\color{green}, % comment color
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}, % keyword color
    stringstyle=\color{red}, % string color
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    basewidth = {.48em}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={C++ code using listings}]
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    // print hello to the console
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: C++ code using lstings]

Comment: +1 for this is the real answer that reduces the width without affecting other features of the text (like mono-space)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `breaklines=true` so that the lines are broken in to two.

```
\documentclass{article}
% source code listing
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}

% citation style
\usepackage{apacite}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true,label=some-code,caption=bind to service call]     %% <---here
bindService(new Intent(this, Recognizer.class), recConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add that to `\lstset` in the preamble? He may also want `columns=fullflexible` (and perhaps `basicstyle=\ttfamily`).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That is a fair possibility. But my crystal ball is greasy ;-)