# Spacing for typewriter font looks off without fulflexing option in lstlisting

Tags: fonts, spacing, listings, verbatim, kerning

I'm trying to get the spacing and font to look clean in my `lstlisting` output window. Right now, if I enable the `columns=fullflexible` option, it makes the font truly monospaced and it perfectly aligns the brackets. Unfortunately, this makes the font, when outputting text, look bad.

[image]

If, on the other hand, I disable this option, the font looks much better but completely misaligns brackets.

[image]

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds, i.e., aligned brackets but without the large no-kerning issue?

MRE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newtxtext, pifont, newtxmath, tcolorbox}
\renewcommand{\ttfamily}{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont}

\tcbuselibrary{listings, skins, breakable}

\lstdefinelanguage{Scheme}{
  columns=fullflexible, % <--- Disabling this gets the bad font but proper bracket alignment
  sensitive=true,
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color[rgb]{0,.3,.7},
  frameshape={RYR}{Y}{Y}{RYR}
}
\title{Font Tests}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Here is some text without the typewriter font. \texttt{Here is some using it.} Below is code in a verbatim block.
\begin{verbatim}
(define value-of-function
  (lambda (exp env)
\end{verbatim}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Scheme]
(define value-of-function
  (lambda (exp env)
    (let ([name (cadr exp)]
          [formals (get-formals (cddr exp))]
          [body (list (get-body exp))])
      ...)))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also see the second answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263428/250119 (not just the first)

Comment: @user202729 Excellent! That second reference helped.